# Cannot Set Focus when using Allow Additions property

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have built a database with MS Access called Task Tracker. I have my main form set as a splitform.  I am trying to force users to use the "Add New Record" button I've created, rather than being able to click on the * row in the splitform datasheet. To this end, I have set the property "Allow Additions" to No, which obviously prevents me from creating new records with this form.

To get around this, I am trying to use VBA triggered by the "Add New Record" button to set the Allow Additions property to Yes, create the new record, and then set it to No again. The only problem is: after setting the form to allow additions, a line of code setting the focus to a control on my form generates the error "Task Tracker can't move the focus to the control Owner".  This is before I set the "Allow Additions" property back to false.

If I do not include the Allow Additions lines, there is no error.

I moved some code around and now it takes issue with setting focus on a completely different control, so it isn't control-specific.

How are these two things even related?

Here is the code in this section:

```
Public Sub NewTaskSetup()
On Error GoTo NewTask_btn_Click_Err
    Me.AllowAdditions = True
    Me.Owner.SetFocus
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    Me.TaskName = TempVars!newTaskName
    Me.Assignees.SetFocus
    For i = 0 To Me.Assignees.ListCount - 1
```

The rest of the code is irrelevant here. In this configuration, the control that generates the error is Me.Assignees.

For further detail: the New Record button opens a Modal Dialog form, prompting the user for a task name.  Clicking OK on this form closes the modal dialog and then calls the function NewTaskSetup() (above).

Thank you for taking the time to consider my dilema.

**UPDATE:**

I have changed my code so that the following code happens before I even open the modal form.  I am still getting a "cannot move focus" error on the Me.Assignees.SetFocus line:

```
Private Sub NewTask_btn_Click()
On Error GoTo NewTask_btn_Click_Err

    Me.AllowAdditions = True
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Me.Owner = TempVars!userIdNum
    Me.Assignees.SetFocus
    For i = 0 To Me.Assignees.ListCount - 1
```

By the time the focus is being set, the record already has an auto-numbered ID and has been saved.  I don't understand what prevents the focus from being set.

Comment: Make sure the modal form is closed and/or focus is back on main form before trying to set focus or it won't be able to find the control.

Comment: I did suspect that might be a contributing factor, so I made sure the code closed the modal form first - HOWEVER, the call to run the NewTaskSetup() is within an If statement, so the code still has to return to the modal form's code module to close it out and exit the sub.  If this is the reason for my error, I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: I have edited my original question to reflect some more troubleshooting attempts I have made today.

Comment: Is Assignees enabled?

Comment: It is.  Another thing I realized may be a contributing factor is that the Assignees field is required.  A number of work-arounds I've tried all stumbled on that issue, so I have now lifted the required status.  That ended up fixing it, although I don't know why.

Comment: The reason might be related to what you said: "By the time the focus is being set, the record already has an auto-numbered ID and has been saved." That would mean that the Assignees field has been given a value already or somehow the record has been saved without a value in there, which shouldn't be possible because it's required.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was hoping.  However, now I have lifted the Required Field status and after a brief period of functioning properly, it has begun to throw up errors again.  Changes I made before it started giving me the error shouldn't affect this portion of code, but I guess what do I, merely a human, know...

Comment: I just undid some of the aforementioned changes that revived the error and have it working again.  I've determined that somehow, setting the Cancel value to TRUE in the BeforeUpdate event trips this error.  Commenting out this line eliminates the problem.  Unfortunate, because I want to set that value...